# Dealing with empty sequence returned by xsl:evaluate

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am using xsl:evaluate to get the value an XPath points to.

Example code:

```
<xsl:variable name="input" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:evaluate xpath="$someXPath" context-item="."/>
</xsl:variable>
```

It works fine, but if the XPath I am passing to xsl:evaluate is wrong and points to nothing I get this error when it tries to assign the empty value to the $input variable:

> XTTE0570  An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of variable
> $input

I also tried it this way (adding as="xs:string" to xsl:evaluate)

```
<xsl:variable name="input" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:evaluate xpath="$Variable[@type=$EXnn]/@element" context-item="$Attribut" as="xs:string"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

but I get the same type of error:

```
Dynamic error in expression {myXPath} called using xsl:evaluate.
  Caused by net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: An empty sequence is not allowed as the
  result of the expression {myXPath} evaluated by xsl:evaluate
```

How should I deal with the case where the XPath does not return anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type the variable as `as="xs:string?"` it should work to store an empty sequence or a string.

Comment: Would you have the reference in the specification where the ? is explained?

Comment: Sorry should have added this to my original question. How do I then check if $input is empty so I can display a xsl:message?

Comment: Look into the XPath 2 or 3 or 3.1 spec for sequence types.

Comment: As for checking for an empty sequence, well, there is a function of that name for that task: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-empty

Comment: Specifically, the syntax of sequence types (and hence the `as` attribute) is defined at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-sequencetype-syntax